# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /trail.jsp at line 16

Tags: java, file, jsp, tomcat, include

I am having Jsp file under root folder in Tomcat and i want to include another jsp file which is placed under webapps folder. while i am trying following code

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
<jsp:include page="../docs/index.html"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

i am getting the following exception

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /trail.jsp at line 16

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /trail.jsp at line 16

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /trail.jsp at line 16

13:     </head>
14:     <body>
15:         <h1>Hello World!</h1>
16: <jsp:include page="../docs/index.html"/>
17:     </body>
18: </html>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    org.apache.jsp.trail_jsp._jspService(trail_jsp.java:73)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.
```

Please help me to include the jsp under webapps folder in tomcat.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

the file in webapps/doc/ will not be in the same context as trail.jsp.  You can not include a jsp from another context.  Although according to the code you are trying to include a static file.  If this is right please update your description.

Comment: I am giving docs folder for example... It maybe any other folder.

Comment: I guess my key message is that you can not include resources from another webapp.  So if you webapp was called FOO and your jsp is then FOO/index.jsp then you can not include BAR/header.jsp.  If this is not the case please provide exactly what you are trying to include, and from where

Answer (score 0):

Try from the directory `WEB-INF/views` (`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views`)

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp" />
```

[image: Webapp Structure]